# How to avoid individual patch updates

Tags: netlogo

I am modeling diffusion in my model, but I think I am getting a calculation artifact due to NetLogo sequentially updating individual patches. I will not be using the **diffuse** command (due to inaccurate diffusion). However, much like how this command works, I would like to update all the calculations of the patches simultaneously, rather than sequentially. I have a slight recollection of seeing some sample code that used values at the beginning of the **tick**, however I can´t seem to find it now.

Specifically, I need help programming a way to store patch values at the turn of each tick, and then carry out a simultaneous calculation based on these stored values.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what inaccuracies have you run into with `diffuse`?

Comment: Hi Bryan, thank you for this nice coding trick. I have not tested the inaccuracy of the diffuse command myself. I have seen claims that the non-homogenous distance between self and neighbors (corner patches are further than non-corner patches) causes inaccuracy. However, like I say I havent tested this myself, and simply took the statement of another research group. Instead a finite difference scheme can be used to approximate the PDEs in Ficks Law. This has been my approach. Let me know if you are interested getting the code, I would be happy to share.

Comment: Just a note that `diffuse4` doesn't have the non-homogeneous distance issue.

Comment: This brings up a good point, I haven`t thought of this. In fact my model is simulating diffusion, however between boundry conditions with fixed concentrations, I need a bi-linear interpolation to calculate concentrations between some fixed nodes. I can`t figure out why using the average of `neighbors4` is not giving the correct interpolation. Yet interpolation using `diffuse4` gives a correct bilinear interpolation if repeated. My  problem using `diffuse4` is that I must interpolate in specific planes (so I use `patch-at`). Perhaps I should pose this as a question to make the problem clearer?

Comment: I have resorted to posting my problem as a new question. I cant seem to figure out a bilinear interpolation process for what I need. Thanks for your helpful comments and code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question. As you indicate, basically you want to calculate the new value of the variable in one `ask` block, but store it in a separate variable, and then update the actual value of the variable in a second `ask` block, like so:

```
turtles-own [
  value
  new-value
]

...
to go
  ask patches [
    ;; Change this line to however you want the diffusion to work
    set new-value 0.5 * value + sum [  0.5 * value / 4 ] of neighbors4
  ]
  ask patches [
    set value new-value
  ]
end
```

This way all patches calculate their updated values from the same information, and then actually update the values themselves simultaneously.