# Bi-Linear Interpolation by Diffusion vs Neighbors Average

Tags: netlogo

In my model I need to carryout bi-linear interpolation of a patch-variable. Certain patches contain a fixed patch-variable (lets call these nodes). For all non-nodal patches, I need to obtain the value of patch-variable by bi-linear interpolation. However, the distance between nodes is not always the same, so I am trying do the interpolation by a "diffusion-like" algorithm (nodes as boundry conditions and with repeated iterations, non-nodal points settle on the linear path between boundry condtions). Since my model is in 3D, I need to perform Bi-linear interpolation in certain planes (xy xz yz), thus I havent found a way to simply use diffuse4. I tried using repeated averaging of neighbors4 ( or `patch-at` to give the correct plane) while holding the patch-variable at nodes constant. Yet I cant figure out why this is not giving a correct bi-linear interpolation. Essentially my method follow the code below. If the interpolation was correct, I would expect all patches to have the same `value`as the nodes, but they do not.

```
globals 
[ 
nodes
non-nodes

]

patches-own [ value]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks

  set nodes (patch-set patch -2 -2 patch 2 -2 patch -2 2 patch 2 2) 
  set non-nodes (patch-set patches with [ abs pxcor <= max-pxcor and abs pycor <= max-pycor and not member? self nodes ]) 


  load-nodes  ; inputs data
  ask nodes [ set value 1 ]

  ask patch 0 0 [ show value ]
end

  to go


if ticks mod 1000 = 0 [
  load-nodes 
  Bi-lin-Interpolate                  
]

ask patches [
;  set value value1
  set pcolor scale-color yellow value 5 100]

tick

end

to load-nodes 
  ask nodes [ set value ((ticks / 1000) + 1) ] 
end

to Bi-lin-Interpolate
  repeat 10000 [ 
    ask patches [ set value ( sum [value] of neighbors4) / 4 ]
    load-nodes ]
  ask patch 0 0 [ show value ]
  ask patch 2 2 [ show value ]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems suspect:

```
ask patches [ set value ( sum [value] of neighbors4) / 4 ]
```

You're just discarding the value at the current patch.

If you want to update all of the values at once, you need to follow the advice at [How to avoid individual patch updates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25976846/86485).